# How to use the Reddit API securely? (HTTPS)

Tags: api, http, ssl, https, reddit

Does the Reddit API allow HTTPS requests? If yes, for which API calls are they allowed and what is the URL? For maximum security am I OK in only using HTTPS for the login request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of this writing, reddit does not support API requests over HTTPS when authenticated via cookies (however, the authentication flow **should** be done over HTTPS). However, if using [OAuth](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2), HTTPS is **required**. The downside is that only API endpoints [accessible via OAuth](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api/oauth) can be used; though the majority of common endpoints are covered, there are a few missing.